# Handling JVM crash

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I am accessing DLL's using JNI in my application. Sometimes the application crashes, writing this message to the logfiles:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment.
```

I tried to handle this using `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(jvmShutdownHook);`
but that did not work.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you please post more details , like full error log.

Comment: What are the DLL's you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Might help to put a try-catch Throwable and print error messages within blocks that call the dlls.

Are you using a logger like slf4j or log4j? Can you add the lines of code that your calling to your question and info about which dlls? If its propritory - then will be difficult to help but maybe you can try similar with a known public dll to make sure its nothing about the general enviorment or way of using JNI that is causing issue.

Sample code :

```
try{
    logger.log("entering code location XXX"); //replace XXX with 1-3 words more meaningful and unique
///do something with JNI
}catch(Throwable e){
    logger.warn("Error at XXX " + e, e);
}
```

Make sure you do *not* compile with :

> -g:none - Generate no debugging info

Default is to include all debug information so do not need to change anything if you have not customized earlier. Different tools have different ways of specifying this. Depends on your compile and build method (batch, ant, maven, etc)

Sample XML config if using log4j this will print class name and line number of error. to log file and console:

> http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'
>   debug="false">
>
> ```
>  <appender name="consoleAppender"
>   class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
>   <param name="Threshold" value="ALL" />
>   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
>      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
>   </layout>    </appender>
>  <appender name="fileAppender"
>        class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
>   <param name="Threshold" value="ALL" />
>   <param name="File" value="log/tfwCore.log"/>
>   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
>      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
>   </layout>    </appender>
>  <logger name="com.tf4" additivity="false" >
>   <level value="ALL" />
>   <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
>   <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>    </logger>
>
>  <logger name="org.apache.http.wire" additivity="false" >
>   <level value="ALL" />
>   <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
>   <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>    </logger>
>
>
>  <logger name="org.apache.http.headers" additivity="false" >
>   <level value="ALL" />
>   <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
>   <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>    </logger>
>    <!--  Context Logging -->
>    <logger name="org.apache.http.impl.client" additivity="false" >
>   <level value="ALL" />
>   <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
>   <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>    </logger>
>
>      <logger name="org.apache.http" additivity="false" >
>   <level value="ALL" />
>   <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
>   <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>    </logger>   </log4j:configuration>
> ```

More info on apache log4j and slf4j sites (or can use Java logging or simple system out printlns too)

Answer (score 0):

Have you written the DLL by yourself? Then you have most possibly defined a native function with a wrong signature, or you're using the JNI functions wrong. Take a look at the [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) documentation. Add your suspicious code snippet to get further support here.

If you're using a third-party library, than there is no way to simply *catch* the error, because native errors that cause the VM to crash are in most cases not resolvable for the JVM.